# Log message on Android: /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base

Tags: android, memory, logging, message

I've just "finished" my new application. When I test it with my low cost tablet (a lot of free memory available) everything seems ok. But if I run it on my HTC phone sometime I see a message in the Log window:

```
11-04 22:11:34.570: D/memalloc(16419): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x527a0000 size:6144000 offset:4608000
```

I've difficulties to find an explanation for this message. Can someone explain it?

Comment: More than 30 days after, none knows anything about?

Answer (score 2):

Found this:

> The pmem driver is used to manage large (1-16+MB) physically contiguous 
>   regions of memory shared between userspace and kernel drivers (dsp, gpu,
>   etc).  It was written specifically to deal with hardware limitations of
>   the MSM7201A, but could be used for other chipsets as well.  For now,
>   you're safe to turn it off on x86.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-kernel/U05uERWkPKg